# How to remove yourself from an event on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How do I remove an event from My Events? I can't find the old "Remove This Event" link anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**To remove yourself from the guest list (as opposed to simply declining).**

1. Decline the event.
2. Go to the event page.
3. Bring up the guest list. (Click on "Going" "Maybe" or "Invited")
4. Switch the view to **Declined** using the drop-down.
5. Find your name.
6. Hover over your name and notice the X to the right of it.  Click that X and it will ask you if you want to remove the event.

*This might not work with private events*

NOTE: If you have not responded/RSVP'd to the event, simply click on the event. Do not RSVP. Your name will appear as one of the first names on the left, which will make it easier to remove instead of going through the Declined dropdown.

Comment: Man that's some complicated ish. Facebook really is trying to play hide and seek.

Comment: @phwd: More like just hide and don't seek lol.

Comment: Un-accepting since it doesn't work anymore. (Sorry...)

Comment: Not sure if this is new — you don’t have to decline! There should be an `x` next to your name in the “invited” list in the left bar.

Comment: Now you have to go to https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity?category_key=invitedevents&privacy_source=access_hub&entry_point=ayi_hub

Answer (score 4):

Just discovered how to do it after coming here for help.

Just go to the event and look for your name under "Invited"—there is the little `X` you can use to remove it from your events. You don't have to do all the declining, etc. first.  This means you don't appear as *Declined* on the event, and don't receive all the notifications when, say, someone writes on its Wall.

Just another example of FB leaving in the same functionality but changing how you access it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alex that does not resolve the ops question. If you remove yourself from an event you will show up under declined. It does not appear possible to remove yourself from declined and from the event altogether. You can click the x next tyo your name in the declined list and a popup does appear telling you that you are removed from the event, however you are not actually removed and your name remains in the declined list. Another example of facebook making a simple task complicated. They make clean water dirty!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook used to have a "Remove from my events" link at the sidebar of an event page. Now, you just say "Not attending" and it is removed from your list.

Comment: The problem isn't *my* list that bugs me, it's the *event*'s list that still shows me in the Not Attending section. Removing myself from the event list is not the same thing as removing the event from my list...

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry buddy, I can't find anything either :/