# How do I remove myself from an event on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide events in Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/how-do-i-hide-events-in-facebook)
>   [How to remove yourself from an event on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20243/how-to-remove-yourself-from-an-event-on-facebook)

It used to be that I could remove myself from an event on Facebook. This way, I would not be notified of updates to the event or other such things. It also removed me from the invited list.

When Facebook's timeline feature was rolled out, removing oneself from an event was still doable, though it required a workaround.

Yesterday, however, I tried to remove myself from an event and could not figure out how. Has this ability been removed from Facebook entirely? Will declining an event now function in the same way as a removal?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20243/how-to-remove-yourself-from-an-event-on-facebook http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15474/how-do-i-remove-myself-from-a-facebook-event-invitation-list

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise The "How do I hide events in Facebook?" question is a year old and so out of date. The first of the latter two links is more what I was looking for.

Comment: There is a new answer in one of those questions. You may want to check them.